# change height of row of listview based on length text in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview. I assign to the listview a simple adapter. I add data but sometimes the text is bigger than expected. All rows of the listview have the same height. However if i add the word "Afghanistannnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn" the text will not fit into the listview row. So my question is the following. How do i change the row height of the listview based on the length of the text so it is fully visible?

Here is my list item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:paddingStart="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

here is my main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
        "India",
        "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "China",
        "Bangladesh",
        "Nepal",
        "Afghanistannnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn",
        "North Korea",
        "South Korea",
        "Japan"
    };
 
    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
        R.drawable.india,
        R.drawable.pakistan,
        R.drawable.srilanka,
        R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.bangladesh,
        R.drawable.nepal,
        R.drawable.afghanistan,
        R.drawable.nkorea,
        R.drawable.skorea,
        R.drawable.japan
    };
 
    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
        "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee",
        "Sri Lankan Rupee",
        "Renminbi",
        "Bangladeshi Taka",
        "Nepalese Rupee",
        "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won",
        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
    };
 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 
        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
 
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }
 
        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };
 
        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};
 
        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listitem, from, to);
 
        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);
 
        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the height of the TextView's container `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:paddingStart="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```